# Nginx proxy_pass to directory in if statement

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

what i want to do is reverse proxy `b.com/c/d/1.jpg` directory with `a.com/1.jpg`

```
location / {
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
       # below will cause error: cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside \"if\" statement,
       # proxy_pass https://b.com/c/d; 
       proxy_pass https://b.com;
    }
}
```

can anyone help? how to do this on right way. THX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `if (!-e $request_filename)` with a [`try_files` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), and place the `proxy_pass` into a [named `location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). Use [`rewrite...break`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) to adjust the URI before it's passed upstream.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /c/d/$1 break;

    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_pass https://b.com;
}
```